# How to test Empty string from database in django?

Tags: mysql, django

I'm having a hard time trying to test weather a record in the database exists for a perticular ID in django.

```
something = User.objects.get(id=myID)
if something is None:
     text="No Record"
```

I need to do something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since rev 11646 (3 months ago) django has a special function for that (see ticket [11402](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11402)):

```
if not User.objects.filter(id=myID).exists():
    text = "No Record"
```

That is more efficient since it generates EXISTS sql statement instead of populating the python object.

Comment: I'm using an older version of django, exist is not allowed sadly.

Answer (score 1):

```
if not User.objects.filter(id=myID):
    text = "No Record"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Antony Hatchkins' solution or:

```
try:
    something = User.objects.get(id=myID)
except User.DoesNotExist:
     text="No Record"
```

EDIT: There is a [shortcut](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) that is very handy:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def my_view(request):
    my_object = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=1)
```

This example is equivalent to:

```
from django.http import Http404

def my_view(request):
    try:
        my_object = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
    except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
```